# Make iframe scrollbar disappear

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am changing the properties of an iframe with javascript like so :

```
var iFrame = window.top.document.getElementById('window_content');
    iFrame.setAttribute("height","63");
    iFrame.setAttribute("scrolling","no");
    iFrame.style.overflow="hidden";
    iFrame.style.height = "63px";
```

It changes size as I would like but the scrollbar will not disappear.  Is this possible?  The html output looks like I would expect :

```
<iframe width="650" height="63" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.google.com/" id="window_content" name="window_content" style="overflow: hidden; height: 63px; width: 650px;"> </iframe>
```

Why is the scrolling attribute not recognized?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working perfectly fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XSfzg/

This is in the latest Google Chrome.

Comment: Yea its weird.. I guess it is because I am re-setting the attributes with js.  If I edit the html in firebug, change anything about the iframe, the scrollbars disappear.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
iframe.style.overflowX = "hidden";
iframe.style.overflowY = "hidden";
```